# NSInternalConsistencyException reason +entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name

Tags: ios, core-data

Was using interface builder to create a view controller, and pass the NSManagedObjectContext to it, doing everything perfect. But I kept getting the error as if I didn't set something up.

I'm posting this because no other question addresses the issue, but hope others will benefit.

After using hard code instead of IB, I noticed that the root view controller's view was called before the App Delegate. That completely messed up the intended order. NSLog has showed me what comes first now.

Many times I severely question Apple's (lack) of use of English grammar, or doing things the way any normal person would expect. This, like the iPad's app store not displaying full names on related programs, is one of those things.

So yes, if you're using NIB's, hardcode the addSubview part instead of linking in Interface Builder. Even if you link it right, hardcode the root view controller. Or, someone with more experience could post another solution...
 I could be off, or way off even, but if so... blame Apple for assuming anyone reading the tutorials will always need to do it "that one way written in the docs".

Core Animation suffers the same missing info and links. Ok now I'm ranting about Apple. If this issue was addressed, though, I apologize, yet all the ones I find are typos and "not linking". I did everything mentioned and it still didn't, which was very confusing.

Thanks!

Comment: Before blaming Apple I would check that the NSManagedObjectContext you pass in `entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` is not nil.

Comment: I won't downvote this "question" but the problem and solution it describes is highly dubious. Even if it is, you might want to provide more detail so that others can understand exactly what is going on.

Comment: I tried to load everything using Nib's for views to stay consistent with the MVC pattern. This problem and solution was not findable anywhere. I posted it so that other people can find it and get help for it if they run into it. The main deviation is I was not hard-coding it. However, my code matches what I linked (Nibwise), I am unsure what happened in many respects.

Answer (score 0):

> I noticed that the root view
>   controller's view was called before
>   the App Delegate...

That is impossible. The app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` has to be called before any view can activate. The overall display window is owned by the app delegate so if the app delegate has not loaded, there is no window for views to load into.

I've created dozens of apps with IB, Core Data and many types of views and view hierarchies and never encountered seen a view load before the app delegate. You've missed something.

The error:

> NSInternalConsistencyException reason
>   +entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name

... either means that your managedObject model has not loaded or that you spelled the entity name wrong. It sounds like your Core Data stack is either not loading or that you are accessing it incorrectly.

Comment: I shoved an NSLog in both, and the one from ViewDidLoad was called first. I can't argue that, I will simply say I watched it happen.

Comment: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/11537-viewcontroller-called-before-applicationdidfinishlaunching.html common issue

Comment: If so, I'd file a bug report. That is not supposed to happen. Now, the `viewDidLoad` of the top view will be called before `didFinishLaunch...` ***completes*** but I've never seen it call viewDidLoad before `didFinishLaunch...` is called at all. I mean, how does the app know which view to load? How does the view find its window?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. What's bizarre is that on iOS 5 I get the problem, and on the iOS 6 I don't.

Some digging revealed that on iOS 6 the context seems to be there when I expect it, when on iOS 5 it's empty (hence the error message). In my case I was giving over the context via a segue. A workaround was to test if the context was nil, and if it was then request it specifically. Did the trick.

This must have been something Apple was aware of as it's changed for iOS6.